# FCM How to get Notification().getTitle() when app open from in background during notification click

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

When app is not running and user clicks on notification it will open splash screen but it getExtras there is no key like title and body. But if app is working and notification sending from `MyFirebaseMessagingService` then it will print title and body. What is the issue here?

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
        switch (key){
            case "body":{
                if(value.contains("order successfully")){
                    orderSuccessfully=true;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        Log.d("readingNotiMain", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value+"  vc:"+value.contains("order successfully"));
    }
}
```

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
/*        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            if (*//* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job *//* true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                handleNow();
            }
        }*/

       // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            if(remoteMessage.getData()!=null){

                Log.i(TAG,"data:"+new Gson().toJson(remoteMessage.getData())+"");
                Log.i(TAG,"don "+new Gson().toJson(remoteMessage.getData()));
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle()
                    +" \n Body"+ remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }
    // [END on_new_token]

    private void scheduleJob() {
//        // [START dispatch_job]
//        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
//        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
//                .setService(MyJobService.class)
//                .setTag("my-job-tag")
//                .build();
//        dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
//        // [END dispatch_job]
    }


    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }


    private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main_Act.class);
        intent.putExtra("body",messageBody);
        intent.putExtra("title",title);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Intent orderPageIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main_Act.class);
        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "ssss",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you sending the `title` and `body`?  Are you using cloud functions?

Comment: Likely it's a duplicate, just too lazy right now to search for the duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Comment: @PeterHaddad i need to get notification title and body it is sending from PHP server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in FCM there is tow type of payload(**Message types**) available, one is `Data` and another one is `Notification`, so If you are using notification payload then when the app is in background you cant handle notification in onReceive and in foreground you can handle it, so I just suggest if you want to handle data in both case use then put only `data` payload don't put `notification` payload

You can reach more understanding from bellow document

[About FCM messages Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

**Here is the server-side payload example**

**With Notification Payload**

```
{"to":"[add your token]","notification":{"title":"Working Good","body":"[add your message]"},"priority":"high"}
```

**With Data Payload**

```
{"to":"[add your token]","data":{"title":"Working Good","body":"[add your message]"},"priority":"high"}
```

Comment: I think this answer solve my issue and now php developer is not available right now after he reach office i will try this and if it works then i will approve this answer

Comment: Okay Sure, We wish it will help you.